# How to set all Classes that can be run to Single Instance only?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can I configure Intellij so that every time I am running or debugging something it will be a single instance only?

I know that I can set it in the run and debug configuration but that is only for one class.

Comment: Are you saying,  classes acting like singletons without actually writing code for it. And just by tweaking settings in IDE only?

Comment: "Single instance only", in an IntelliJ Run Configuration is merely a check box that prevents the user from requesting a run configuration to execute again once it is already executing in the IDE. I use IntelliJ all day, but never used this. Is this really what you want? It's not part of the "Defaults", so there is no way to specify it once for all run configurations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. You may want to vote for the [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98563) to add an option for 'Single instance only' under the defaults setting.